# Unix Network Programming Clarification

Tags: c, sockets, unix, tcp, client-server

I was going through the classic book [Unix Network Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0139498761), when I stumbled upon this program (Section 6.8, page 179-180)

```
#include    "unp.h"

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int                 i, maxi, maxfd, listenfd, connfd, sockfd;
    int                 nready, client[FD_SETSIZE];
    ssize_t             n;
    fd_set              rset, allset;
    char                buf[MAXLINE];
    socklen_t           clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in  cliaddr, servaddr;

    listenfd = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port        = htons(SERV_PORT);

    Bind(listenfd, (SA *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    Listen(listenfd, LISTENQ);

    maxfd = listenfd;           /* initialize */
    maxi = -1;                  /* index into client[] array */
    for (i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; i++)
        client[i] = -1;         /* -1 indicates available entry */
    FD_ZERO(&allset);
    FD_SET(listenfd, &allset);

    for ( ; ; ) {
        rset = allset;      /* structure assignment */
        nready = Select(maxfd+1, &rset, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        if (FD_ISSET(listenfd, &rset)) {    /* new client connection */
            clilen = sizeof(cliaddr);
            connfd = Accept(listenfd, (SA *) &cliaddr, &clilen);

            for (i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; i++)
                if (client[i] < 0) {
                    client[i] = connfd; /* save descriptor */
                    break;
                }
            if (i == FD_SETSIZE)
                err_quit("too many clients");

            FD_SET(connfd, &allset);    /* add new descriptor to set */
            if (connfd > maxfd)
                maxfd = connfd;         /* for select */
            if (i > maxi)
                maxi = i;               /* max index in client[] array */

            if (--nready <= 0)
                continue;               /* no more readable descriptors */
        }

        for (i = 0; i <= maxi; i++) {   /* check all clients for data */
            if ( (sockfd = client[i]) < 0)
                continue;
            if (FD_ISSET(sockfd, &rset)) {
                if ( (n = Read(sockfd, buf, MAXLINE)) == 0) {
                        /*4connection closed by client */
                    Close(sockfd);
                    FD_CLR(sockfd, &allset);
                    client[i] = -1;
                } else
                    Writen(sockfd, buf, n);

                if (--nready <= 0)
                    break;              /* no more readable descriptors */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The author mentions that this program is not safe against DOS attack. Quoting from the book,

*"Unfortunately, there is a problem with the server that we just showed. Consider what happens if a malicious client connects to the server, sends one byte of data (other than a newline), and then goes to sleep. The server will call **read** (system call), which will read the the single byte of data from the client and then block in the next call to **read**, waiting for more data from this client. The server is then blocked by this one client, and will not service any other clients until malicious client either sends a newline or terminates"*

I am not sure if I understand this correctly. Why will the **read** system call be called the second time for this malicious client, since it only sent 1 byte of data, that gets notified by the first call to **select**. The subsequent calls to **select** will never have this malicious file descriptor set as there is no activity. Am I missing something here?

My guess here is that there is a typo in the code, instead of Read, it should be some version of Readline method mentioned at other places in the book.

**Note**: The code contains **Read** and **Select** (with capital R and S), which are nothing but error handled wrappers of **read** and **select** system call

Comment: What's unp.h?  A file from the book?

Comment: yes, it contains declaration for these wrapper methods I mentioned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it seems likely that it was intended to be `Readline`.

In the [downloadable source code](http://www.unpbook.com/src.html) that file is `tcpcliserv/tcpservselect01.c` and there is a corresponding `.lc` file (with line number annotations) which uses `Readline` instead of `Read`, and it was `Readline` in the second edition of the book ([source code](http://www.kohala.com/start/unpv12e/unpv12e.tar.gz)). About the only way to make sense of the parenthetic comment "(other than a newline)" is to assume that the intended read function reads up to a newline.

Oddly, it hasn't been reported [in the errata](http://www.unpbook.com/errata.html). Maybe you should do so.

Comment: Yeah noticed that too. I have already sent the authors an email.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem that he was pointing out was that, as you noted in your NOTE, this code uses `Read` which is a wrapper of `read`.  My guess, since I'm not about to dig out my copy of the book right now, is that `Read` will try to call `read` a second time to finish receiving the data that is never coming.

Comment: The Read function is just this, ssize_t
Read(int fd, void *ptr, size_t nbytes)
{
 ssize_t  n;

 if ( (n = read(fd, ptr, nbytes)) == -1)
  err_sys("read error");
 return(n);
}