# A Denial-of-Service Attack issue in book "Unix Networking Programming"

Tags: sockets, readline, ddos

I'm reading "Unix Networking Programming" the 3ed edition.

I encounter a question in 6.8 section "TCP Echo Server (Revisited)", here present code as below:

```
#include    "unp.h"

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int                 i, maxi, maxfd, listenfd, connfd, sockfd;
    int                 nready, client[FD_SETSIZE];
    ssize_t             n;
    fd_set              rset, allset;
    char                buf[MAXLINE];
    socklen_t           clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in  cliaddr, servaddr;

    listenfd = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port        = htons(SERV_PORT);

    Bind(listenfd, (SA *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    Listen(listenfd, LISTENQ);

    maxfd = listenfd;           /* initialize */
    maxi = -1;                  /* index into client[] array */
    for (i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; i++)
        client[i] = -1;         /* -1 indicates available entry */
    FD_ZERO(&allset);
    FD_SET(listenfd, &allset);

    for ( ; ; ) {
        rset = allset;      /* structure assignment */
        nready = Select(maxfd+1, &rset, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        if (FD_ISSET(listenfd, &rset)) {    /* new client connection */
            clilen = sizeof(cliaddr);
            connfd = Accept(listenfd, (SA *) &cliaddr, &clilen);

            for (i = 0; i < FD_SETSIZE; i++)
                if (client[i] < 0) {
                    client[i] = connfd; /* save descriptor */
                    break;
                }
            if (i == FD_SETSIZE)
                err_quit("too many clients");

            FD_SET(connfd, &allset);    /* add new descriptor to set */
            if (connfd > maxfd)
                maxfd = connfd;         /* for select */
            if (i > maxi)
                maxi = i;               /* max index in client[] array */

            if (--nready <= 0)
                continue;               /* no more readable descriptors */
        }

        for (i = 0; i <= maxi; i++) {   /* check all clients for data */
            if ( (sockfd = client[i]) < 0)
                continue;
            **if (FD_ISSET(sockfd, &rset)) {
                if ( (n = Read(sockfd, buf, MAXLINE)) == 0) {
                        /*4connection closed by client */
                    Close(sockfd);
                    FD_CLR(sockfd, &allset);
                    client[i] = -1;
                } else
                    Writen(sockfd, buf, n);**

                if (--nready <= 0)
                    break;              /* no more readable descriptors */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

About this program, Author said the server will suffer from DDOS attack as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrBfY.jpg)

the point is once a client request come, server read entire line then echo it. But is this code, we see server use Read function read data from client, not ReadLine or Readn, latters won't return until encounter a '\n' or fetch specified size data, but Read function immediately return in this case.
Read function just wrapper of system call "read" as below:

```
ssize_t Read(int fd, void *ptr, size_t nbytes)
{
    ssize_t     n;

    if ( (n = read(fd, ptr, nbytes)) == -1)
        err_sys("read error");
    return(n);
}
```

So I confused why this server will suffer from a ddos attack?

Anyone can clarify it? Thank you very much!

Comment: The example clearly implies the server is single threaded, and the read operation is blocking. Meaning after reading the first byte, the server keeps the connection opened waiting for more, but the client never sends it, thus the server is not available to a second client.

Comment: Also, that is not a DDoS attack, that's just a simple DoS attack.

Comment: Thanks for James's corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the confusion is due to a possible difference between the second edition and third edition of the book.

I have the 2nd edition and in it the "Read" is actually a "Readline".  Then the explanation makes sense, due to the fact that Readline insists on reading until a newline.

I do not have a copy of the 3rd edition to compare with.

As for the explanation from Drunken Code Monkey, true, the read is blocking, however it is protected by the select which will guarantee that the read is only called if there is activity on the socket (either a disconnect, or at least 1 byte to read).  So it is guaranteed that the read will not block.  But see my explanation regarding if Read is replaced with Readline (as in 2nd edition)

See also a previous post on Stack Overflow [Unix Network Programming Clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064833/unix-network-programming-clarification)

Comment: "Blocking" read does not mean blocking forever. The simple fact that the read waits for something is a problem in itself. The example was about a single client, but let's say you have a timeout on the read for 500ms. Now let's say an attacker initiates a barrage of connections exploiting this delay. This is a distributed denial of service attack, and it **will** bring the server to it's knees. The correct way to handle is by spawning a separate thread for every incoming socket connection, immediately, before even reading.

Comment: You are right, thanks you! I have confirmed with author Andy Rudoff, here is his reply: "Yes, you are correct.  This is an error in the book.  The previous edition used readline and so suffered from the issue, but we neglected to change the paragraph when we updated it.  If we even do another edition of this book, it is on my list of things to fix!"

Comment: I wasn't aware 2 other authors had retaken the work of the late W. Richard Stevens. Congrats Joseph on spotting this.

Answer (score 0):

As per Stephane's response, here is an example to illustrate proper connection handling in a threaded TCP server. Note that I am not comfortable enough with linux development to write it easily, so this is C#, but the program flow should be the same. Treat it as pseudo-code if you must.

```
    // We use a wait handle here to synchronize the client threads with the main thread.
    private static AutoResetEvent _waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Start the server on port 1337
        StartServer(1337);
    }

    private static void StartServer(int port)
    {
        // Create a connection listener
        var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);

        try
        {
            // Start the listener
            listener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                // Wait for a connection, and defer connection handling asynchronously.
                listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(HandleAsyncConnection), listener);
                _waitHandle.WaitOne();
                _waitHandle.Reset();
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            // Handle socket errors or any other exception you deem necessary here
        }
        finally
        {
            // Stop the server.
            listener.Stop();
        }
    }

    private static void HandleAsyncConnection(IAsyncResult state)
    {
        // Get the listener and the client references
        var listener = (TcpListener)state.AsyncState;
        using (var tcpClient = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(state))
        {
            // Signal the main thread that we have started handling this request.
            // At this point the server is ready to handle another connection, and no amount
            // of tomfoolery on the client's side will prevent this.
            _waitHandle.Set();

            // Declare buffers
            var inBuff = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
            var outBuff = new byte[tcpClient.SendBufferSize];

            // Get the connection stream
            using (var stream = tcpClient.GetStream())
            {
                try
                {
                    // Read some data into inBuff
                    stream.Read(inBuff, 0, tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);

                    // Do something with the data here, put response in outBuff...

                    // Send response to client
                    stream.Write(outBuff, 0, outBuff.Length);
                }
                catch (SocketException ex)
                {
                    // Handle socket errors or any other exception you deem necessary here
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I assume there is code missing in the "\\Read some data into inBuff // Send response to client section" - what if there are fewer bytes read than tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize? Or tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize != outBuff.Length?

Comment: If there is less data than the ReceiveBufferSize, the Read call will timeout after TcpClient.ReceiveTimeout. If you expect incoming data larger than you can realistically buffer, you have to call Read multiple times until there is no more data. The example as it is fully functional for appropriately sized messages, but yes you may want to flourish the send and receive code appropriately. The important part is that at this point it doesn't matter, because the request is being serviced on a separate thread. The server listener became available again the moment we _waitHandle.Set().